# must be str, not bytes | 'str' has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, string, mongodb, python-3.x

I have this simple code to extract from a mongo database:

```
import sys
import codecs
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)

mongo_db = "database"
collectionId = "coll name"

def main(argv):
        client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
        db = client[mongo_db]
        collection = db[collectionId]

        cursor = collection.find({})
        for document in cursor:
        #       if "content" in document:
        #            sys.stdout.write(
        #                    "|"+(document['content'] if document['content'] is not None else "")+"\n")
                for key, value in document.items() :
                        sys.stdout.write(key.decode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

running it like this, gets me

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

So... it's a str object, then? but if I remove the decode, I get

> TypeError: must be str, not bytes

and, it's not like it's printing anything, so, it must be failing at the first key? but... can the first key be neither str nor bytes??? how can I print this?

EDIT testing with flush:

```
                for key, value in document.items() :
                    sys.stdout.write("1")
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    sys.stdout.write(key.decode('utf-8'))
                    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I changed the for to that, getting the error

```
~/Desktop$ python3 sentimongo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentimongo.py", line 30, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "sentimongo.py", line 24, in main
    sys.stdout.write("1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 374, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: You are on Python 3.x. Strings have no `decode` method. If you need a bytes object from a string, then `encode` should do.

Comment: There are probably some bytes and some str keys. You could try `print(list(document.keys())` to see what kind of keys there are.

Comment: Since you’re using `sys.stdout.write`, consider adding a `sys.stdout.flush()` afterwards so the output updates immediately. That way you can tell whether your two runs (with and without decode) yield a different amount of keys (they probably do).

Comment: @poke look at the new data on the edit.... could it be because I'm having to call it via an argument to python3? Because, it's not even printing that 1, and I have a similar script that extracts from mysql that gives no such error, but uses python 2.7

Comment: also, I tested that "1" with both decode and without it, didn't get printed either way

Comment: ran it with python 2.7, by just doing "./script.py" and it worked... so, I'm still wondering if it's python3, or having to do "python3 script.py"

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)` line. You should remove that.

Comment: @poke yeah, that worked. if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
```

This line changes the standard output, so it does different things than you normally see. In Python 3 you don’t really need to care about converting things to utf8 since everything already is a unicode string.

If you remove that line, writing a normal string (or even printing one) should work fine.